# Text animation using Css/Js not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm currently working on a Text Animation that uses jQuery/CSS. You can find a link here.

https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/MWePMPX?editors=0110

The problem I'm facing is in the second line -

> > Insta's @TheFitFlyingFoodie

When the animation runs, the "ie" in the end gets cut, and doesn't run as a part of the animation.

Can someone help me on how to solve this issue in my code.

[HERE IS MY PROJECT ON CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/MWePMPX?editors=0110)

This is my code if it helps -

### HTML

```html
<main>
  <section class="mast">
    <figure class="mast__bg" style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/1800/800?image=893)"></figure>
    <header class="mast__header">
      <h1 class="mast__title js-spanize" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px">PRAGYA RAGHAW</h1> 
      <h2 class="mast__title js-spanize" style="margin-top:-18px;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">Insta's @theFitFlyingFoodie</h2> 
      <hr class="sep"/>
      <p class="mast__text js-spanize">
This is a story, all about how, 
My life got twisted upside down. 
So I'd like to tell a story, just sit right there. 
And I'll tell you how I became the prince of Bel Air.</p>

    </header>
  </section>
</main>
```

### CSS

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.sep {
  border: 0;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.mast {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111;
}
.mast:after {
  z-index: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
}
.mast > header {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.mast__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
.mast__header {
  padding: 5%;
}
.mast__title {
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.mast__title span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
          animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
          animation-delay: 0.05s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
          animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
          animation-delay: 0.15s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
          animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
          animation-delay: 0.35s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
          animation-delay: 0.45s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
          animation-delay: 0.55s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
          animation-delay: 0.65s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
          animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
          animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
          animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(17) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.85s;
          animation-delay: 0.85s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(18) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
          animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(19) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.95s;
          animation-delay: 0.95s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(20) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(21) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.05s;
          animation-delay: 1.05s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(22) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
          animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(23) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.15s;
          animation-delay: 1.15s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(24) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
          animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(25) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.mast__text {
  font-family: "Cutive Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: pre;
}
.mast__text span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
          animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
          animation-delay: 0.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
          animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
          animation-delay: 0.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
          animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
          animation-delay: 0.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
          animation-delay: 0.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
          animation-delay: 0.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
          animation-delay: 0.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
          animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
          animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
          animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(17) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.85s;
          animation-delay: 0.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(18) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
          animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(19) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.95s;
          animation-delay: 0.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(20) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(21) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.05s;
          animation-delay: 1.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(22) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
          animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(23) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.15s;
          animation-delay: 1.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(24) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
          animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(25) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
          animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.35s;
          animation-delay: 1.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(28) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
          animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(29) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.45s;
          animation-delay: 1.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(30) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
          animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(31) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.55s;
          animation-delay: 1.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(32) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
          animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(33) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.65s;
          animation-delay: 1.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(34) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
          animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(35) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.75s;
          animation-delay: 1.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(36) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.8s;
          animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(37) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.85s;
          animation-delay: 1.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(38) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.9s;
          animation-delay: 1.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(39) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.95s;
          animation-delay: 1.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(40) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(41) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.05s;
          animation-delay: 2.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(42) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.1s;
          animation-delay: 2.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(43) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.15s;
          animation-delay: 2.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(44) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
          animation-delay: 2.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(45) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.25s;
          animation-delay: 2.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(46) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
          animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(47) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.35s;
          animation-delay: 2.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(48) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.4s;
          animation-delay: 2.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(49) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.45s;
          animation-delay: 2.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(50) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
          animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(51) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.55s;
          animation-delay: 2.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(52) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.6s;
          animation-delay: 2.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(53) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.65s;
          animation-delay: 2.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(54) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
          animation-delay: 2.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(55) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.75s;
          animation-delay: 2.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(56) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.8s;
          animation-delay: 2.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(57) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.85s;
          animation-delay: 2.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(58) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.9s;
          animation-delay: 2.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(59) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.95s;
          animation-delay: 2.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(60) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(61) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.05s;
          animation-delay: 3.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(62) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.1s;
          animation-delay: 3.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(63) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.15s;
          animation-delay: 3.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(64) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.2s;
          animation-delay: 3.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(65) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.25s;
          animation-delay: 3.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(66) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.3s;
          animation-delay: 3.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(67) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.35s;
          animation-delay: 3.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(68) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.4s;
          animation-delay: 3.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(69) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.45s;
          animation-delay: 3.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(70) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
          animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(71) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.55s;
          animation-delay: 3.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(72) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.6s;
          animation-delay: 3.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(73) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.65s;
          animation-delay: 3.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(74) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.7s;
          animation-delay: 3.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(75) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.75s;
          animation-delay: 3.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(76) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.8s;
          animation-delay: 3.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(77) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.85s;
          animation-delay: 3.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(78) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.9s;
          animation-delay: 3.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(79) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.95s;
          animation-delay: 3.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(80) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(81) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.05s;
          animation-delay: 4.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(82) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.1s;
          animation-delay: 4.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(83) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.15s;
          animation-delay: 4.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(84) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.2s;
          animation-delay: 4.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(85) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.25s;
          animation-delay: 4.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(86) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.3s;
          animation-delay: 4.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(87) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.35s;
          animation-delay: 4.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(88) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.4s;
          animation-delay: 4.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(89) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.45s;
          animation-delay: 4.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(90) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
          animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(91) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.55s;
          animation-delay: 4.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(92) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.6s;
          animation-delay: 4.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(93) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.65s;
          animation-delay: 4.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(94) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.7s;
          animation-delay: 4.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(95) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.75s;
          animation-delay: 4.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(96) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.8s;
          animation-delay: 4.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(97) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.85s;
          animation-delay: 4.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(98) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.9s;
          animation-delay: 4.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(99) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.95s;
          animation-delay: 4.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(100) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
          animation-delay: 5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(101) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.05s;
          animation-delay: 5.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(102) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.1s;
          animation-delay: 5.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(103) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.15s;
          animation-delay: 5.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(104) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.2s;
          animation-delay: 5.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(105) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.25s;
          animation-delay: 5.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(106) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.3s;
          animation-delay: 5.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(107) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.35s;
          animation-delay: 5.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(108) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.4s;
          animation-delay: 5.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(109) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.45s;
          animation-delay: 5.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(110) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s;
          animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(111) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.55s;
          animation-delay: 5.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(112) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.6s;
          animation-delay: 5.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(113) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.65s;
          animation-delay: 5.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(114) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.7s;
          animation-delay: 5.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(115) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.75s;
          animation-delay: 5.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(116) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.8s;
          animation-delay: 5.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(117) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.85s;
          animation-delay: 5.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(118) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.9s;
          animation-delay: 5.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(119) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5.95s;
          animation-delay: 5.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(120) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
          animation-delay: 6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(121) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.05s;
          animation-delay: 6.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(122) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.1s;
          animation-delay: 6.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(123) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.15s;
          animation-delay: 6.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(124) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.2s;
          animation-delay: 6.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(125) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.25s;
          animation-delay: 6.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(126) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.3s;
          animation-delay: 6.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(127) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.35s;
          animation-delay: 6.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(128) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.4s;
          animation-delay: 6.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(129) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.45s;
          animation-delay: 6.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(130) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.5s;
          animation-delay: 6.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(131) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.55s;
          animation-delay: 6.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(132) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.6s;
          animation-delay: 6.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(133) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.65s;
          animation-delay: 6.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(134) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.7s;
          animation-delay: 6.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(135) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.75s;
          animation-delay: 6.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(136) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.8s;
          animation-delay: 6.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(137) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.85s;
          animation-delay: 6.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(138) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.9s;
          animation-delay: 6.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(139) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6.95s;
          animation-delay: 6.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(140) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
          animation-delay: 7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(141) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.05s;
          animation-delay: 7.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(142) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.1s;
          animation-delay: 7.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(143) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.15s;
          animation-delay: 7.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(144) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.2s;
          animation-delay: 7.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(145) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.25s;
          animation-delay: 7.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(146) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.3s;
          animation-delay: 7.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(147) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.35s;
          animation-delay: 7.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(148) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.4s;
          animation-delay: 7.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(149) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.45s;
          animation-delay: 7.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(150) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
          animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(151) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.55s;
          animation-delay: 7.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(152) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.6s;
          animation-delay: 7.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(153) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.65s;
          animation-delay: 7.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(154) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.7s;
          animation-delay: 7.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(155) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.75s;
          animation-delay: 7.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(156) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.8s;
          animation-delay: 7.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(157) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.85s;
          animation-delay: 7.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(158) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.9s;
          animation-delay: 7.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(159) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.95s;
          animation-delay: 7.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(160) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
          animation-delay: 8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(161) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.05s;
          animation-delay: 8.05s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(162) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.1s;
          animation-delay: 8.1s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(163) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.15s;
          animation-delay: 8.15s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(164) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.2s;
          animation-delay: 8.2s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(165) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.25s;
          animation-delay: 8.25s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(166) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.3s;
          animation-delay: 8.3s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(167) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.35s;
          animation-delay: 8.35s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(168) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.4s;
          animation-delay: 8.4s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(169) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.45s;
          animation-delay: 8.45s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(170) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.5s;
          animation-delay: 8.5s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(171) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.55s;
          animation-delay: 8.55s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(172) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.6s;
          animation-delay: 8.6s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(173) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.65s;
          animation-delay: 8.65s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(174) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.7s;
          animation-delay: 8.7s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(175) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.75s;
          animation-delay: 8.75s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(176) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.8s;
          animation-delay: 8.8s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(177) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.85s;
          animation-delay: 8.85s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(178) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.9s;
          animation-delay: 8.9s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(179) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.95s;
          animation-delay: 8.95s;
}
.mast__text span:nth-child(180) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
          animation-delay: 9s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

### jQuery

```js
/*-----
Spanizer
- Wraps letters with spans, for css animations
-----*/
(function($) {
  var s,
  spanizeLetters = {
    settings: {
      letters: $('.js-spanize'),
    },
    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
      s.letters.html(function (i, el) {
        //spanizeLetters.joinChars();
        var spanizer = $.trim(el).split("");
        return '<span>' + spanizer.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
      });
    },
  };
  spanizeLetters.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Insta's @TheFitFlyingFoodie" was 27 char long and mast__title had span:nth-child only to 25. You need to add 26:nth and 27:nth child to css and it will start working.

```
.mast__title span:nth-child(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}

.mast__title span:nth-child(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your css only covers animations of words up to 25 letters. if you take a look at it you have this portion of code:

```css
.mast__title span:nth-child([index]) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
```

This code portion is reapeated 25 times for each index. so in order for this to work you need to add

```css
.mast__title span:nth-child(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.mast__title span:nth-child(28) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
          animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
```

While this answers your question, I would suggest you look for a rather dynamic method :) I am sure you will find a way to solve it more cleanly